Gradle: applying plugin from local Maven repository
I have successfully published the artifact into my local m2 repository at location: .m2\repository\com\example\gradle-binary-plugin\1.0 
The name of the plugin is gradle-binary-plugin-1.0.jar 
Now, I am trying to import the plugin in my project. For that my build.gradle looks as below:
plugins {
    id "com.example.gradle-binary-plugin" version "1.0"
}

However, I am getting below error:
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'com.example.gradle-binary-plugin', version: '1.0'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.example.gradle-binary-plugin:com.example.gradle-binary-plugin.gradle.plugin:1.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    MavenLocal(file:/C:/Users/abc%20Gupta/.m2/repository/)


You may have published the artifact, but you may not have published the plugin descriptor correctly. I suggest you share the plugin build and publishing configuration

This is not a duplicate. In the other question, the error message showed Maven Local was not searched (indicating the issue was not specifying that as a repo); here the error shows Maven Local is specified as a repo. In other words, the issue is a different one
